# PC not booting from USB, CD and IDE drive

Tags: windows

I have encountered a problem where hp d510 sff is not booting from any of the drives attached. The drives are recognized in the BIOS but the PC is not booting. Black screen after selecting any of the drives as boot option. I have restored bios settings to default but no luck. PC previously was running win xp. Tried Ubuntu live USB but still No luck...am stuck I NEED Help!

Comment: Is the problem only with Ubuntu or other Linux distros? Please [edit] to clarify. If so the problem is most likely related to the Nvidia Graphics card > Use `nomodeset` as a boot parameter for installing and booting, until you install the proper Nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried a Windows Installation physical disk (CD/DVD) and have tried booting from a couple of different USB sticks with Windows on, (made bootable with something like RUFUS or from the command line) then sounds like you have tried everything! Always worth reseating the RAM and trying a different power supply etc.